# How to make my site allow iFraming

Tags: iframe

Question: I understand some websites don't allow themselves to be iframed. Question is, I own the website that I'm trying to iframe, so is there a setting where I can "allow iframing"?  Would it be in wordpress? Godaddy?  Here's the iframe of my site that I am trying to put somewhere else (doesn't work):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.warlordmarketing.com/" height="2000" width="1000"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Again, to clarify, I don;t mean my site allowing iframes to be placed on it. I mean allowing iframes *of it* to be placed elsewhere.

Comment: is your site https based?

Comment: no, it's only http

Comment: Which website are you putting it in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes iFrames are disabled as a mitigation against clickjacking attempts. It can be done in any number of ways. [Here is a short list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet):

- Content Security Policy (CSP) frame-ancestors directive
- X-Frame-Options Response Headers
- Legacy Browser Frame Breaking Script

In order for your site to be framed, all of the above mitigations would need to be disabled.

Also, if your site requires session cookies, the end user will have to ensure that third party cookies are enabled. Safari has them turned off by default.

Comment: Thanks, John.  How and where would x-frame options be manipulated? Is that at the domain level?  hosting level? within wordpress?

Comment: It's a type of HTTP response header. HTTP headers could be added in many places, but the most likely location is in the configuration for the web site/web server, e.g. IIS configuration or web.config. Depends on your platform. They could also be added via code or by a gateway somewhere, but I would look at the web server first.